# Decimal or integer with negative look behind

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following simple negative look behind

```
(?<![Ø]\s*)
```

And the following expression to match an integer or a decimal whether with or without integer part

```
([0-9]*(?:[.,][0-9]+)?)
```

the second expression matches `8 8.8 8,8 .8 ,88 etc..`

I am trying to combine the 2 expressions to ignore the whole match of the second expression in case its preceded by `Ø`, so I did

```
(?<![Ø]\s*)([0-9]*(?:[.,][0-9]+)?)
```

and those values for testing

```
88.88
88,88
,88
.5
Ø    .8
Ø  8.8
```

First 4 values match as expected but a part of the last 2 gets partially matched and I expected it to not match at all, can someone please tell what i am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
(?<![Ø]\s*|[.,\d])(?=[\d.,]{1,})([0-9]*(?:[.,][0-9]+)?)
             ^^
             ||
```

**[regexstorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5b%c3%98%5d%5cs*%7c%5b.%2c%5cd%5d)(%3f%3d%5b%5cd.%2c%5d%7b1%2c%7d)(%5b0-9%5d*(%3f%3a%5b.%2c%5d%5b0-9%5d%2b)%3f)&i=88.88%0d%0a88%2c88%0d%0a%2c88%0d%0a.5%0d%0a%c3%98++++.8+abc+23%0d%0a%c3%98++8.8%0d%0a%c3%98+33+ddd+57%0d%0a%c3%98+4)**

A bit simpler version suggested by **[bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble)**

```
(?<!Ø\s*|[.,\d])(\d*[.,]?\d+)
```

Comment: this looks like it works but can you please explain what the `.` did?

Comment: @Bread yup that's the problem..it will not match any line if it contains `Ø`

Comment: i appreciate you help don't waste much time on it ;)

Comment: looks like this one is working perfectly, will offer some bounty in 2 days in exchange for your time, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Always better to explain answers on SO. So here we go: the problem is that the expression can actually match *anywhere in the string*. Thus, if the test case has more than one character in the match it might fail on, then a match will *start one character in and match the rest.* Even more so given that the expression given can match some blank strings. The best way of doing things would be to:

1. Add a check to make sure that the match has at least one digit, and
2. Add a check to make sure that it is at the start of a potential match.

Both of these can be done with the negative lookbehind. Thus: `(?<!Ø\s*[.,\d]*)\d*[.,]?\d+`